# White fiberglass looking material inside fireplace - what is it?

Tags: fireplace, asbestos

I can see this white fiberglass looking material between the top of the aluminum hood inside the fireplace and surrounding metal. Is it dangerous? I am thinking asbestos, or is this fairly normal to put fiberglass in the fireplace like this?

[image]

Comment: How old is the fireplace?

Comment: It was built in 1981

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many non-asbestos high-temperature fiber insulations (Kaowool, Superwool, rockwool, etc.) - but as with all asbestos questions, you can't tell by looking, so send a sample to a lab if it's of an age where asbestos is possible.

Fiberglass won't take the heat, so it's not that.

Comment: I guess the other question is, even if it is, is it dangerous? We never operate the fireplace.

Comment: If you don't disturb it, it's not a problem. Probably not a problem even if you used the fireplace - only if you were doing something to release fibers into the air of the house would it be a concern. But 1981 is also getting late for application of asbestos.